# Comparing two Lists in java

Tags: java

In an application we have a Boarding table having ( boarding_id + invoice_no + item_id ) as key. A Boarding_tmp table with same table structure as Boarding. We are loading Boarding_tmp from a csv file (pipe separator column values)

We have a Boarding java bean with all columns. Let's say we have two list -

```
1. boardingList with all active records in Boarding table
2. boardingTmpList with all records in Boarding_Tmp table
```

I need to compare these two list to implement below scenario -

We Need to compare Boarding table with Boarding_tmp table and need to do following (No SQL joins. We have to perform this on object level) -

```
a. All records which are in Boarding_tmp but not in Boarding table should be inserted in Boarding table (means they are new records)
b. All records which are in Boarding but not in Boarding_tmp table should be mark as deactivated in Boarding table (we have a active column in Boarding table)
```

Here in Boarding.java -

```
public class Boarding implements Comparable {

    private String bordingId;
    private String itemId;
    private String invoiceNo;
    private String itemName;
    private long qty;
    private double price;

    /**
     * @return the bordingId
     */
    public String getBordingId() {
        return bordingId;
    }

    /**
     * @param bordingId
     *            the bordingId to set
     */
    public void setBordingId(String bordingId) {
        this.bordingId = bordingId;
    }

    /**
     * @return the itemId
     */
    public String getItemId() {
        return itemId;
    }

    /**
     * @param itemId
     *            the itemId to set
     */
    public void setItemId(String itemId) {
        this.itemId = itemId;
    }

    /**
     * @return the invoiceNo
     */
    public String getInvoiceNo() {
        return invoiceNo;
    }

    /**
     * @param invoiceNo
     *            the invoiceNo to set
     */
    public void setInvoiceNo(String invoiceNo) {
        this.invoiceNo = invoiceNo;
    }

    /**
     * @return the itemName
     */
    public String getItemName() {
        return itemName;
    }

    /**
     * @param itemName
     *            the itemName to set
     */
    public void setItemName(String itemName) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
    }

    /**
     * @return the qty
     */
    public long getQty() {
        return qty;
    }

    /**
     * @param qty
     *            the qty to set
     */
    public void setQty(long qty) {
        this.qty = qty;
    }

    /**
     * @return the price
     */
    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    /**
     * @param price
     *            the price to set
     */
    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see java.lang.Object#hashCode()
     */
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result
                + ((bordingId == null) ? 0 : bordingId.hashCode());
        result = prime * result
                + ((invoiceNo == null) ? 0 : invoiceNo.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((itemId == null) ? 0 : itemId.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (o == null) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return 1;
        }
        Boarding other = (Boarding) o;
        if (bordingId == null) {
            if (other.bordingId != null) {
                return 1;
            }
        } else if (!bordingId.equals(other.bordingId)) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (invoiceNo == null) {
            if (other.invoiceNo != null) {
                return 1;
            }
        } else if (!invoiceNo.equals(other.invoiceNo)) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (itemId == null) {
            if (other.itemId != null) {
                return 1;
            }
        } else if (!itemId.equals(other.itemId)) {
            return 1;
        }

        return 0;
    }

}
```

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [Collections Util](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html) library. They have very useful methods for the scenario you depicted.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do the following:

```
List<Boarding> insertBoarding = new ArrayList(boardingTmpList);
insertBoarding.removeAll(boardingList);
// insert all elements in insertBoarding to the table
List<Boarding> deactivateBoarding = new ArrayList(boardingList);
deactivateBoarding.removeAll(boardingTmpList);
// deactivate all elements in deactivateBoarding in the table
```

Assuming your equality tests work, this should yield correct results.

**NOTE:** You will have to override the `equals` method for this to work properly.

Comment: Thanks. I have checked this but getting same list every time. Is my compareTo logic wrong?

Comment: You will need to override the `equals` method for this to work, I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

That's easily achivable with use of `List#retainAll` method.

javadoc is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html#retainAll%28java.util.Collection%29)